# Android Log Collector

Tags: android, android-logcat

Is there any application for collecting log messages for **specific application**? or is't possible?

I have already used `log collector`. It collects the device logs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#logcat):
    adb logcat ActivityManager:I MyApp:D *:S

Comment: This does not log everything from one application. It only shows the log statements with the TAG MyApp on level debug and ActivityManager on level info. Unfortunately what you want is impossible. Logcat does not distinguish on a per app basis.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible. You can only filter logs by TAG. If you know all the TAGs one app is using you can do something like this:

```
adb logcat  tag1:D tag2:D \*:S
```

This will log tag1 and tag2 on level debug and not anything else. S means silence and the \ is for your shell. otherwise * (for all) will be interpreted by your shell.